# How do I make a variable in a module on a global namespace?

Tags: python, namespaces

I have been working on a module that takes a file name and a file line and creates a variable defined by the user and it works. But I want the variable to be on a global namespace here is the code:

```
def Int(file, line, variable):
    file = open(file, "r")
    for i in range(line):
        whatToConvert = file.readline()
    file.close
    globals()[variable] = int(whatToConvert)

def Str(file, line, variable):
        file = open(file, "r")
        for i in range(line):
            whatToConvert = file.readline()
        file.close
        globals()[variable] = str(whatToConvert)

def Float(file, line, variable):
        file = open(file, "r")
        for i in range(line):
            whatToConvert = file.readline()
        file.close
        globals()[variable] = float(whatToConvert)
```

If I import convert then do convert.Int("test.txt", 1, "var_1") then the var ("var_1") is accessible by convert.var_1 not var_1 how can I make var_1 on a global namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a class, bro.

```
class Converter:

    def __init__(self, fl, ln, vrbl):
        self.file = fl
        self.line = ln
        self.variable = vrbl


    def to_int(self):
        file = open(self.file, "r")
        for i in range(self.line):
            whatToConvert = file.readline()
        file.close
        return int(whatToConvert)

    def to_str(self):
        file = open(self.file, "r")
        for i in range(self.line):
            whatToConvert = file.readline()
        file.close
        return str(whatToConvert)

    def to_float(self):
        file = open(self.file, "r")
        for i in range(self.line):
            whatToConvert = file.readline()
        file.close
        return float(whatToConvert)


#Instantiation
foo = Converter('\a\path','an int?','')

#This is how you call the class methods.
foo.to_int()
foo.to_str()
foo.to_float()
```

I don't know exactly what your input is supposed to look like, but you can get what you want from this.  And you can store class definitions in other files and import them just like modules.

`from filename import Converter`

Then you would just instantiate, etc., like I wrote.  This might change some of what you envisioned for your program, but it might make it easier too.

The `__init__()` function happens on the line where you do `foo = Converter('\a\path','an int?','')`  You may want to think about putting the `open` statement there and then saving values in variables with names like `self.variable`.  Then anywhere in the class you can make reference to `self.variable`.  Notice that `self` is the first argument of every method definition.  `self` means the object itself.  There may be many ways to make a class that does what you want.

Comment: Seeing that your `to_x` methods do not use `self` at all I'm pretty sure he simply wants a bunch of functions. Python is not Java where you must create fake classes to group together what should really be functions.

Comment: A class makes the most sense to me if he wants to share the same data between those various functions, as he was alluding to.  I do use `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Docs of [globals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) state it explicitly that it is a module-wise global dictionary

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This
>   is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or
>   method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from
>   which it is called).

You could pass `globals()` as an argument (that would be globals from your current module). Still messing with globals, especially in that way, looks like a very bad idea.